# Tricky Indeterminate Power With Indeterminate Solution

Tags: limits, indeterminate-forms

I have learn in *L'hospital rule* about indeterminate power, we will take $\ln$ to find the limit. 
But in this question, I suspect there is no solution to the limit.

$\lim_{x\to \infty}({\frac {2-3x}{1+6x})^x=\lim_{x\to \infty}\exp(x\ln(\frac{2-3x}{1+6x}))}$

Where it also equal $\lim_{x\to\infty}\exp(x\ln(\frac{-1}{2}+\frac{5}{2(1+6x)}))$

Then the exponent can be rewritten into, $\exp(\frac{\ln(\frac{-1}{2}+\frac{5}{2(1+6x)})}{\frac{1}{x}})$ but this is not indeterminate form.

Because as $x\to\infty$, $\ln(\frac{-1}{2}+\frac{5}{2(1+6x)})\to\ln(\frac{-1}{2})$, but $\ln\frac{-1}{2}$ is not  defined.
So, can I say that the limit is indeterminate?

I am trying to show that the limit is indeterminate.

Comment: The problem is that $\left(\frac{2-3x}{1+6x}\right)^x$ is not defined for large $x$. Are you sure some sign is not misplaced in the problem?

Comment: @fwd My thought s exactly. To the author, see here -https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+calculator&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22Limit%22%2C+%22limitfunction%22%7D+-%3E%22%28ln%282x-3%29-ln%28x%2B6%29%29%2Fx%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22Limit%22%2C+%22limit%22%7D+-%3E%220%22

Comment: @fwd No, the problem given was for x to approach infinity. But it seems that this is not possible

Comment: @IshraaqParvez So, the limit will yield complex solution?

Comment: Apparently, yes.

Comment: @IshraaqParvez Ok, thank you.